# Does existence of column linear combination imply existence of row linear combination?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be (n x n) matrix made up of column vectors $A^1,...,A^n$, b be some arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Suppose that b can be written as a linear combination of the column vectors of A: i.e., there exist real numbers $c_1,...,c_n$ (not all zero) such that $b=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i A^i.$

Let $A_1,...,A_n$ be the row vectors of A. Then is it true that b can be written as a linear combination of the row vectors of A? (i.e. do there exist constants $k_1,...,k_n$ not all zero so that $b=\sum_{i=1}^n k_iA_i$)

Comment: This is certainly true if $A$ is symmetric. What if $A$ is not symmetric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question boils down to the following one: Does the row space of a matrix always equal the column space? If the matrix is square and of full rank, that is sufficient, as is being symmetric, but the statement is not true in general.

For instance take $n = 2$ and $A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}1 & 2\\ 3& 6 \end{array}\right]$. Then the row space of $A$ is multiples of the vector $(1,2)$ but the column space is multiples of the vector $(1,3)$, and the two spaces are clearly distinct.

However, it is true that the dimension of the row space is always equal to the dimension of the column space, given by the rank of the matrix.

Comment: Great, thanks! To confirm the sufficiency of square matrix with full rank:

1) Rank of matrix = column rank = row rank
2) n column vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$ are lin indep, hence form a basis for $\mathbb{R^n}$. Same for row vectors. So both span $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Is this right?

Comment: I presume you're asking me to confirm, or do you have a proof yourself? Either way, if $A$ has full rank, then it has $n$ linearly independent rows, so the rows form a basis for your space. Similarly, it has $n$ linearly independent columns, and they span the space as well. So we can create any vector as linear combinations of the rows or columns since they form a basis.

Comment: Pressed enter on accident, needed to hold shift. Sorry about that. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Oops, sorry for spilling the beans instead of letting you write your own answer. Either way, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

No. Although the row-rank of the matrix is equal to its column rank, the column-vectors and the row-vectors (transposed) do not span in general the same subspace.

Counter-example:

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. The column vector $C_2$ is not a linear combination of $\;{}^{\mathrm t\!}R_1$ and $\;{}^{\mathrm t\!}R_2$.